# Запятые. Одиночное деепричастие ("Пришел к твоей сестре(,) не предупредив")

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

**Прости, что пришел к твоей сестре(,) не предупредив, но дело было срочное.**

Можно заменить "не предупредив" на "без предупреждения", поэтому не следует ставить запятую?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прости, что пришел к твоей сестре **не предупредИв,** но дело было срочное.

1) Одиночное деепричастие "не предупредив" в текстах в Нацкорпусе **обособляется в большинстве случаев,** но структура предложений при этом такова, что можно сделать паузу, например:

Но они никогда не приехали бы ко мне из СарАтова, не предупредИв. [Сергей Лукьяненко. Ночной дозор (1998)]

...очередной шофер Дуся ушлА, не предупредИв, добирался на такси. [А. Т. Твардовский. Рабочие тетради (1970) // «Знамя», 2005]

2) Тем не менее, если важно перенести ударение на деепричастие, не делая паузы, то **обособлять его не нужно** (здесь важна **позиция наречия**, а не то, что можно деепричастие заменить наречием "без предупреждения"):

Но однажды она появилась у него **не предупредИв**, объявила, что приехала в районную поликлинику...[Владимир Железников. Чучело (1981)]